# How to know a group radio button object is selected in hp/uft

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am trying to click a radiogroup object in a web page consisting 4 options, I would like to select an option then refresh the page followed by need to verify whether the initial option is saved or retained

Answer (score 0):

Radio Buttons are meant for user inputs representing one choice from a few possible ones where each one is fairly important and the choice should be transparent for the user(In the case of a List / Select you also have one from many; but the number of choices can be bigger and the value differences are not as significant to be displayed all). Because of this concept we tend to think that Testautomation Robots handle the RadioButton (Group) as one Object with multiple choices. The case is that it is not: Each option is a different ´RadioButton Object so you need capture and iterate over each one and see if the value is ON or OFF `.GetROProperty("value") = "ON"`. Whichever is **ON is the selected one.** (there will be only one)

Comment: So how can we determine whether the selected object order by index?

Comment: A for each loop is failing to iterate over array of radio buttons returned from childobjects method

Comment: That's not an array, but a Collection Object. You Need:
       `
       Dim colRadioButtons, objARadioButton

       Set colRadioButtons = BaseObject.ChildObjects(RadioButtonProperties)
       For i = 0 To colRadioButtons.Count - 1
            Set objARadioButton = colRadioButons.Item(i)
            REM Check Something on the Button
            Next
       `

Answer (score 0):

UFT usually groups radio button in one test object called a **WebRadioGroup**. Using this object, you will be able to query its current selection by using method **.GetROProperty("value")**.

```
Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebRadioGroup("WebRadioGroup").Select "Yes"
Print Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebRadioGroup("WebRadioGroup").GetROProperty("value")
```

Hope this helps.